# Calculation occurance random numbers in csv file

Tags: python, excel, csv, pandas

I have a csv file with the columns: recipe_name (index), apple, citrus, banana, melon, ... (and more columns with fruits). 
For each recipe there is a row with the weight percentages of each fruit. But not all recipes contain all fruits. These are empty spaces in the csv file. 
It looks like this:

> `recipe_name    apple    citrus   banana    melon
>   pudding 1     0.45     0.78
>
>   pudding 2              0.23      0.15     0.12`

Now I want to know the number of fruits in each recipe. So I want to create an extra column and if the first recipe for example contains kiwi, banana and apple, in this extra column the number 3 have to be there. So like this:

> `recipe_name    apple    citrus   banana    melon   count
>   pudding 1     0.45     0.78                           2
>
>   pudding 2              0.23      0.15     0.12        3`

I tried to figure this out in Excel, pandas DataFrame, pandas groupby.. but I didn't found a solution.. Anybody an idea?

Comment: `COUNT` would work in excel, [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.count.html) would work in pandas. There is no need for `groupby`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.count.html) on the cols of interest and pass param `axis=1`:

```
In [217]:
df['count'] = df.ix[:,'apple':].count(axis=1)
df

Out[217]:
  recipe_name  apple  citrus  banana  melon  count
0   pudding 1   0.45    0.78     NaN    NaN      2
1   pudding 2    NaN    0.23    0.15   0.12      3
```

Comment: Thank you very much EdChum! It worked great! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
import csv

with open(yourFileName, 'rU') as f:
    data = {row[0]:len([x for x in row[1:] if x]) for row in csv.reader(f, yourDialect)[1:]}
```

this will give you a dictionary with keys as recipe names and values their fruit count!